# Python: Threading does not let the rest of the program run

Tags: python, multithreading

In my program, when a thread starts, only the thread runs while the rest of the program waits for it. Here is the program:

```
import socket
from time import sleep
import threading
import string

class IRC:
    "IRC Module for python"
    def __init__(self, HOST, PORT, NICK, REALNAME, IDENT):
        print "New Connection"
        self.s=socket.socket( )
        self.s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        self.s.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))
        self.s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
        self.rb="ReadBuffer"
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.ping())
        t.start()
        print "started thread"
    def read(self):
        readbuffer=readbuffer+self.s.recv(1024)
        temp=string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
        readbuffer=temp.pop( )
        return temp
    def ping(self):
        "Handles Pinging"
        readbuffer=""
        print "Started pinging"
        while True:
            readbuffer=readbuffer+self.s.recv(1024)
            temp=string.split(self.rb, "\n")
            readbuffer=temp.pop( )
            for line in temp:
                line=string.rstrip(line)
                line=string.split(line)
                if(line[0]=='PING'):
                    self.s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
                    print("Ponged")
                    self.pinged=True
            print "ran"
    def send(self, message, channel):
        self.s.send("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (channel, message))
```

Comment: `t = threading.Thread(target=self.ping())` This will call `self.ping` in your main thread and attempt to pass its return value to `Thread`. Try `Thread(target=self.ping)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the comment already solved your problem, there's not much more to say. Here's what [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) says:

> class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(),
> kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)
>
> This constructor should always be called
> with keyword arguments. Arguments are:
>
> group should be None; reserved for future extension when a ThreadGroup
> class is implemented.
>
> **target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method.**
> Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

So you should set `target` to a callable, which is the `self.ping` method, rather then call it.